# comparison of two mean curves

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, t-test, multiple-comparisons

I have two mean values based on the same sample of people, call them $x_1$ and $x_2$. I know that to compare two means, I would usually use a t-test. However, what I have is a plot of each against a continuous variable $y$ (e.g. average consumption of alcohol plotted against age in years, and average consumption of cigarettes plotted against age in years). My question is how to answer the question whether the two mean functions $x_1(y)$ and $x_2(y)$ are statistically significantly different? Is there some test based on integrating the difference between the two? What I did so far is to calculate the 95% confidence interval for the difference $x_1-x_2$ using the delta method to approximate the variance. So I have a curve $x_1-x_2$ plotted against *age* with a 95% CI around it. May I conclude that because 0 is not in the interval (the curve never crosses the x-axis), the difference between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is significant for any age? Or is there some other more rigorous method available? Many thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What kind of interval calculation is it? Just pointwise?

Comment: yes, pointwise.